# How to manage session in supertokens?

Tags: nestjs, token

I am using the supertokens-node library to manage users in my nest.js app.
I want to protect some of the routes and for that I am using the verifySession method of the supertokens. I am using the postman to test the routes but I am getting unauthorised in the response.

This is the AuthGaurd function as per the docs:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly verifyOptions?: VerifySessionOptions) {}
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const ctx = context.switchToHttp();

    let err = undefined;
    const resp = ctx.getResponse();
    // You can create an optional version of this by passing {sessionRequired: false} to verifySession
    await verifySession(this.verifyOptions)(ctx.getRequest(), resp, (res) => {
      err = res;
    });

    if (resp.headersSent) {
      throw new STError({
        message: 'RESPONSE_SENT',
        type: 'RESPONSE_SENT',
      });
    }
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

This is the endpoint that is I have applied the AuthGuard

```
@Post('/bulkAddUpdate')
  @UseGuards(new AuthGuard())
  async builkAddUpdate(
    @Body() bulkData: any,
    @Session() session: SessionContainer
  ) {
    console.log(session.getUserId());

    const user = await this.applicationService.bulkAction(bulkData.data);
    if (user) {
      return utils.sendSuccess(SUCCESS.S200.DEFAULT, user);
    } else {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
  }
```

As per the [docs](https://supertokens.com/docs/session/testing/testing-with-postman) when I sign-in I have to set the headers rid(key) : session(value) in the signin method but when I hit the request I am getting 404 route not found error. But when I remove rid from the headers then it works perfectly fine.

And I am also setting headers as rid : session to my protected route but I am getting unauthorised in the response.

This is the cURL request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9000/applications' \
--header 'rid: thirdpartyemailpassword' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: pga4_session=887a38e7-589c-4faa-9bbe-139e9145b535!iTseBPH6uzAlV9Mbaap/agtBJ6GymXNDEp+4cgySEdA=; sFrontToken=eyJ1aWQiOiJkMzU0ZTJlOS1hNGVlLTQwOGYtYTQ5My0yYjQ1NjBhYWFiYzkiLCJhdGUiOjE2NzU0MjMzODc4NDAsInVwIjp7ImlzUGFzc3dvcmRsZXNzIjpmYWxzZX19; sIRTFrontend=d131494f-dbd8-4a21-a5a8-3959bb2d4fd1' \
--data-raw '{
    "userID": 2,
    "applicationContent": "<html><body>Anything...</body></html>",
    "applicationType": 200
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The sign in API should not have the `rid` as `session`. The `rid` should be set to the recipe you are using that exposes the signin API. For example, if you are using the EmailPassword recipe, you want to set the `rid` to `emailpassword` when querying the sign in API.

Once you call the sign in API successfully, you should get back session tokens in cookies which are managed by Postman.

Then when you query your protected API, Postman should automatically add the sAccessToken cookie in the request which is verified by the supertokens-node SDK.

Comment: I am using the thirdpartyemailpassword recipe and in the signin process Ihave set the rid to thirdpartyemailpassword in the headers and now it works successfully but on the subsequent request I am still getting the unauthorised in the response

Comment: Make sure that the sAccessToken cookie and sIdRefreshToken cookies are sent in the request.